# sap.m.TablePersoController multiple tables personalization

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to apply a single table personalization to multiple tables. This is the instantiation of my tableperscontroller:

```
var oProvider;
if (sap.ushell) {
    // Create a persistence key
    var oPersId = {
        container: "persistanceContainerB1",
        item: "persistanceItemB1"
    };
    oProvider = sap.ushell.Container.getService("Personalization").getPersonalizer(oPersId);
} else {
    oProvider = TablePersoService;
}

// Init and activate controller
this._oTPC = new TablePersoController({
  tables: [this.oTable, this.oTableHeader],
  componentName: "com.cap.rtt2",
  persoService: oProvider
}).activate();
```

But it does not apply to both of them, only for one. The columns of the tables are the same, although the table ID's do differ.

I do see the personalization mapping in the sap.m.TablePersoController.

I use this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1c60212834c049ed9f65d743dfeb3d9a for reference.

Does anyone have experience with applying the personalization to 2 or more tables?

Thank you in advance,